# What are the different memory management mechanisms in situations where garbage collection is not needed

Tags: memory-management, garbage-collection

I have often read about the garbage collected being more of a burden and that it slows down the program. So I just wanted to know what are the different memory management mechanisms that exists (other than C-like manual management) that one could use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [pool-allocation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_pool) or [smart pointers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer)(a.k.a C++-like memory management)